# Does the echo command create a swap file when it writes a line to a file?

Tags: swap, echo, write

I am currently working on a personal project, and I would like to simply record logs in the following way using the echo command.

My question is if the echo command accesses the same file at the same time, will the swap file be created? Or is there a queue inside the echo command to make things work in order?

example:

```bash
$ cat a.txt

aa
bb
cc
```

```bash
$ echo "apple" >> a.txt

aa
bb
cc
apple
```

Comment: Are you asking how the `>>` append operator works if you run `echo something >> a.txt` multiple times in parallel? "the echo command accesses the same file at the same time" ... same time as what?

Comment: "a swap file" ? What do you mean ? A backup of the file prior to writing ? Do you refer to a behavior like vi(m) when editing some file and some other process writing that file concurrently ?

Comment: _"if the echo command accesses the same file at the same time"_ -- same time with what? _"will the swp file be created?"_ -- what, exactly, do you mean with a "swp file"? _"is there a queue inside the echo command to make things work in order?"_ -- what do you mean with "in order"?

Comment: I want to log the logs of two different projects into a single file.
The two projects work independently of each other.

Then the idea came to me to write a line to a file using the echo command.

However, I ask a question because I don't know what will happen if the two projects access the file at the same time.

This means that while process 1 is writing a log file, process 2 accesses the same log file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the `echo` command, but more about **redirection**. When you redirect the output of any command to a file using `>` or `>>`, the **shell** opens the file and writes directly into it, it has no intermediate temp file in the process. So yes, it is possible that if two processes try to write to the same file at the same time there would be unexpected results, such as that one will override the text the other one wrote.

A possible solution would be using `flock` to ensure that only a single process can access the file at a given time, and if other processes try to write there, the `flock` command will wait for the lock on the file to be released. For instance:

```
flock a.txt echo "apple" >> a.txt
```